# Invalid Group By Function :: MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-like

Firstly, I've read through the posts with matching names, and I've tried integrating some of the solutions but I cant seem to get this SQL Query to work...

The problem seems to revolve around the COUNT function on line 8.

Here it is..

```
SELECT `purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id`,`purchase_orders`.`sequence_id`,`purchase_orders`.`order_number`,`vendors`.`name`,`purchase_orders`.`date`,COUNT(`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`) `item_count`,`purchase_orders`.`total_value`,`purchase_orders`.`status`,`users`.`first`
FROM (`purchase_orders`, `vendors`, `purchase_order_items`,`users`) 
WHERE `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` LIKE '%122%' 
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `purchase_orders`.`sequence_id` LIKE '%122%' 
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `purchase_orders`.`order_number` LIKE '%122%' 
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `vendors`.`name` LIKE '%122%' 
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `purchase_orders`.`date` LIKE '%122%' 
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND COUNT(`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`) LIKE '%122%'
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `purchase_orders`.`total_value` LIKE '%122%' 
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `purchase_orders`.`status` LIKE '%122%' 
OR `purchase_orders`.`aid`='c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'AND`purchase_orders`.`vendor_id`=`vendors`.`vid`AND`purchase_orders`.`created_by`=`users`.`uid`AND`purchase_order_items`.`purchase_order_id`=`purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` AND `users`.`first` LIKE '%122%'  
GROUP BY `purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id`
ORDER BY `purchase_orders`.`purchase_order_id` ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `COUNT(xxx)` in a SQL, you need to use it in the HAVING clause:

e.g.

```
HAVING COUNT(xxx) > yyyy
```

Also, generally you want to GROUP BY the fields that you don't use aggregate functions on. For example:

```
SELECT person_name
     , SUM(bonuses)
  FROM person x
     , person_bonus y
 WHERE x.person_id = y.person_id
```

GROUP BY person_name

As I add additional columns to that SELECT statement, I need to either use another aggregate function (COUNT, SUM, etc.) on them, or I need to GROUP BY them.

And again, anything you are using an aggregate function on can be used in your HAVING clause:

```
    SELECT person_name
         , SUM(bonuses)
      FROM person x
         , person_bonus y
     WHERE x.person_id = y.person_id
   GROUP BY person_name
     HAVING SUM(bonuses) > 50000  // I wish :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you may have selected a solution to your question, however, your query is really unclean.  The premise of SQL is to identify the relationships once on how the table relate on given keys and applying whatever EXTRA filters in the where.  Your query had "OR"s multiple times.  Here's a more cleaned-up version of your query.  Notice the where clause has the ONE key "aid" you were looking for, and a single AND clause to join the tables...  Under the query are the remaining AND clauses where you had so many elements with LIKE '%122%' which a COUNT( of anything ) would be returning a number.

```
SELECT 
       po.purchase_order_id,
       po.sequence_id,
       po.order_number,
       v.name,
       po.date,
       COUNT( poi.purchase_order_id) item_count,
       po.total_value,
       po.status,
       users.first
    FROM 
       purchase_orders po,
       vendors v,
       purchase_order_items poi,
       users
    WHERE 
           po.aid = 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'
       AND po.vendor_id = v.vid
       AND po.purchase_order_id = poi.purchase_order_id
       AND po.created_by = users.uid
   GROUP BY 
       po.purchase_order_id
   ORDER BY 
       po.purchase_order_id
   LIMIT 
       0, 1
```

These I didn't understand what you were looking for, but would end up being AFTER all the other WHERE clauses I had above... Again, the COUNT(poi.purchase_order_id) LIKE '%122%' I don't think is applicable.  Probably the other "ID" based columns which I would assume are numeric based.

```
       AND po.purchase_order_id LIKE '%122%' 
       AND po.sequence_id LIKE '%122%' 
       AND po.order_number LIKE '%122%' 
       AND v.name LIKE '%122%' 
       AND po.date LIKE '%122%' 
       AND COUNT(poi.purchase_order_id) LIKE '%122%'
       AND po.total_value LIKE '%122%' 
       AND po.status LIKE '%122%' 
       AND users.first LIKE '%122%'
```

It appeared you INTENDED to apply all the join conditions for every instance but should have been -- for clarification

```
where 
     ( all first group of conditions )
  OR ( all next group of conditions )
  OR ( all next, etc )
```

I hope this helps clarify how querying is structured.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and examples. But its a lil more complicated that it initially seems. That query is generated from a another query that is parsed and then rebuilt with any options defined by the user.. such as search keywords, sorting order, limit, paging.. etc. 

Here is what Im doing.. http://datatables.dyndns-web.com/main/basic#TheSQL

Comment: @Peter, yeah, but from what is being built, you should still have a CORE query for the relationships, and only tack on the extra WHERE components.  As you can see from my example, they didn't have to be repeated, nor open for "OR" conditions allowing for bigger problems.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try and refactor this thing to build better queries and Ill def use your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Rules for using GROUP BY clause:

1. The column that you GROUP BY must also be in your SELECT statement.
2. Remember to group by the column you want information about and not the one you are applying the aggregate function on.

In you example, you are checking for purchase_order_items.purchase_order_id = purchase_orders.purchase_order_id and also you are applying an aggregate function COUNT(purchase_order_items.purchase_order_id )